# Are there any actions professors can take online to contribute towards "service requirements"?

Tags: professorship, tenure-track, assistant-professor, service-activities

I would like to fulfill my service requirements for the tenure review process.  My question: Is it possible to help fulfill these requirements through on-line activities?  E.g. Mentoring students online, or participating in some sort of on-line collaborative community?

Comment: Can you give more context to the question for better understanding.

Comment: That's going to be up to whoever is implementing and reviewing this policy for your school. Ask them.

Comment: @MrMeritology Although I voted to re-open this question because it makes some sense to me. But, I have a question for you: How do you know the service requirements is for the tenure review process? The OP did not say that.

Comment: @scaaahu: The question was tagged *tenure track* from the beginning.

Comment: I voted to close as the service requirements very wildly by departments, divisions, and schools. It's impossible to give a definitive answer for the OPs particular case. The question should be written more generally.

Comment: I don't really understand the "online" restriction. In this day and age, practically every interaction between people will involve some online component. Are you saying you specifically want to avoid having to interact with people any other way? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

@keshlam's comment is correct:  this is a question for the folks in your department. There are activities (internal and external) that feel like "service" that are not viewed as "service" ... it varies by department and school.  Just like expectations for research and teaching.

And make sure you ask folks who are giving you fact-based, not opinion-based answers.  You should have a tenured faculty mentor (if you don't, get one!), but they might not know the facts on this.  There should be an RPT chair in your department or school:  ask them.  You might also ask your chair:  if they chair views what you are doing as reasonable service, they may be able to argue for it counting, even if it's unusual.

But, in the end, this is not a question for anyone outside your school.  We don't vote. :)